# Why h2 get CLS > 100 - h2 is on category page Prestashop

Tags: optimization, prestashop, cls

(mobile page) CLS checker for chrome and metrics show  bad element h2 on category page? Why? I know how CLS works, but in this case I have no idea why I have CLS so high. The bad result is also visible in the GSC

[shop cavaricci](https://cavaricci.pl/16-sukienki)

Answer (score 0):

In a quick review it looks like the fallback font is smaller than your loaded font "popins".

There are a few options here

1. use a default system font.
2. Change how the font gets loaded this will require a little reading, and being prestashop it probably wont be easy.  See this article on css tricks https://css-tricks.com/the-best-font-loading-strategies-and-how-to-execute-them/

   - Set the font-display property in css
   - add a pre-load meta tag to the head of your page for each font file you will use, be careful not to load the same font twice in different formats. (see https://3perf.com/blog/link-rels/ for more info) e.g `<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v19/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJfecnFHGPc.woff2">`
3. Set explicit width and heights on your title (not ideal if you are using a CMS)